# Appending the output of a 'for' loop to a list (Python)

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to Python, and am just grasping the concept of the 'for' loop. I have generated a loop to print out several differences, but I cannot seem to append all of them to a list.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
# Question 1
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from numpy import log


y0 = [10,1] # [Prey, Predator] units in hundreds

pd = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000, 1100, 1200,
     1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000]

for x in pd:
    t = np.linspace(0.,50.,num=x) 

    alpha = 0.1
    beta = 0.02
    gamma = 0.4
    delta = 0.02

    params = [alpha, beta, delta, gamma]

    def sim(variables, t, params):

        # Prey population level
        x = variables[0]

        # Predator population level
        y = variables[1]


        alpha = params[0]
        beta = params[1]
        delta = params[2]
        gamma = params[3]

        dxdt = alpha * x - beta * x * y
        dydt = delta * x * y - gamma * y

        return([dxdt, dydt])


    y = odeint(sim, y0, t, args=(params,))

    lv_prey = y[:,0] # saving prey population separately
    lv_pred = y[:,1] # saving predator population separately

    prey_array = np.array(lv_prey) 
    pred_array = np.array(lv_pred)

    # Fit a cubic spline
    num_pts = 10
    tsp = np.array([t[i] for i in range(0, len(t), len(t)//num_pts)])

    # Prey
    prey_sp = np.array([lv_prey[i] for i in range(0, len(t), len(t)//num_pts)])
    Curve1 = CubicSpline(tsp, prey_sp, bc_type = 'natural', extrapolate = False)

    # Predator
    pred_sp = np.array([lv_pred[i] for i in range(0, len(t), len(t)//num_pts)])
    Curve2 = CubicSpline(tsp, pred_sp, bc_type='natural', extrapolate=False)

    prey_extrap_dots=Curve1(tsp)
    prey_extrap_line = Curve1(np.array([tt for tt in t if tt<=tsp[-1]]))
    pred_extrap_dots=Curve2(tsp)
    pred_extrap_line=Curve2(np.array([tt for tt in t if tt<=tsp[-1]]))

    # Fit the invariate for the Lotka-Volterra model
    Cspline = alpha*np.log(pred_extrap_line) - beta*(pred_extrap_line) - delta*(prey_extrap_line) + gamma*np.log(prey_extrap_line)
    diff = np.max(Cspline) - np.min(Cspline)
    diffList = []
    diffList.append(diff)
    print("The difference is {}".format(diff))
```

When I call the `diffList` command, only the last output of the loop is appended.

How can I append the `diff` values to a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting `diffList` to an empty list every time just before you append `diff` in your 3rd last line.  You should move this initialization to before the `for` loop so it only happens once:

```
diffList = []
```

Comment: Well that was simple! Thanks, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing something like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    squares = []
    squares.append(i * i)
```

What is happening is that for every iteration of the for-loop a new empty list `squares` is created. That means that after the loop is over `squares` will only contain the value appended on the last iteration.

Instead create your list *before* your for-loop:

```
squares = []
for i in range(10):
    squares.append(i * i)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call  empty diffList  before the for loop